# Aggregate HQL result to list

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I want to group some sql data using criteria. Lets start with entity which looks mostly like this:

```
class CityEntity {
    private String name;
    private Date lastVisited;
}
```

What I want to do is to find all cities and return result in a tranformer:

```
class CityTransformer {
    private String name;
    private List<Date> lastVisited;
}
```

So as you  can see sql result should group by name and put dates to a list.

I want to do it using criteria so it will look almost like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CityEntity.class, "ce");
criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("name"), "name"));
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CityTransformer.class));
List<CityTransformer> cities = criteria.list();
```

The problem is that I don't know how to aggregate dates (lastVisited) to list. Any help?

For example the input will look like this (name, lastVisited):

```
[Los Angeles, 10-11-2014],
[Los Angeles, 11-12-2011],
[LosAngeles, 10-01-2011],
[Berlin, 01-10-2011]
```

and output should look like this

```
[LosAngeles, list[10-11-2014, 11-12-2011, 10-01-2011]],
[Berlin, list[01-10-2011]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SQL grouping for that. You can group it in Java:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CityEntity.class, "ce");
criteria.setProjection(
        Projections.projectionList()
                .add( Projections.property("ce.name"), "ceName" )
                .add( Projections.property("ce.lastVisited"), "ceLastVisited" )
);
List<Object[]> citiesAndDates = (List<Object[]>) criteria.list();
Map<String, CityTransformer> cityTransformerMap = new HashMap<String, CityTransformer>();
for(Object[] citiesAndDate : citiesAndDates) {
    String city = (String) citiesAndDate[0];
    Date date = (Date) citiesAndDate[1];
    CityTransformer cityTransformer = cityTransformerMap.get(city);
    if(cityTransformer == null) {
        cityTransformer = new CityTransformer();
        cityTransformerMap.put(city, cityTransformer);
    }
    cityTransformer.getLastVisited().add(date);
}
return cityTransformerMap;
```

Comment: Yes, I know that but I don't want to create this boilerplate code if it is possible. Hibernate can aggregate sql results to objects so why it can't aggregate result to transformer in the same way?

Comment: Hibernate can build entity relationship graphs but not on projected data. Projects are mapped to DTOs in a one-on-one fashion.